# Why no output when I run the code of A-star algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm

I try to use python to implement A-star algorithm, but when a finish the code and try to use the shortest_path fuction, there is no output and no error, could anyone help me to find out the reason?
This is my judge code, sorry for not have the right to put all the code here:

```
# When meet a point, judge what to do next, the point has a data structure of (name, distance to goal)：
# map.intersections[start] is to find the coordinate of the start point in the map. 
def judge(map, point_cur, point_near, point_target, dictionary_ep, dictionary_ft, dictionary_fs):
    for i in dictionary_ep:
        if point_near[0] != i:
            for j in dictionary_ft:
                if point_near[0] != j:
                    dictionary_ft[point_near[0]] = (point_cur[1] + distance(map.intersections[point_cur[0]], map.intersections[point_near[0]]) + distance(map.intersections[point_near[0]], map.intersections[point_target[0]]))
                    dictionary_fs[point_near[0]] = point_cur[0]
                else:
                    if dictionary_ft[j] <= (point_cur[1] + distance(map.intersections[point_cur[0]], map.intersections[point_near[0]]) + distance(map.intersections[point_near[0]], map.intersections[point_target[0]])):
                        dictionary_fs[point_near[0]] = point_cur[0]
                        dictionary_ft[point_near[0]] = (point_cur[1] + distance(map.intersections[point_cur[0]], map.intersections[point_near[0]]) + distance(map.intersections[point_near[0]], map.intersections[point_target[0]]))
    return 0
```

And this is my whole plan of the A-star:

1. F = G(the path length from the current point to the start point)+H(the assumed distance from the current point to the goal point
2. Put the start block into the dictionary of frontier.
3. Repeat the circle:

   a)      Find the minimum value of F in the dictionary frontier, that point can   be called current point

   b)  Switch the current point to the explored dictionary

   c)  Actions to the adjacent points of current point:

   ```
      If the point is in the explored dictionary, skip over it.  

      If the point is in the frontier dictionary, add it into the dictionary and regard the current point as the father point of this point(put them into the Father_Son dictionary).

      If the point is already in the frontier point, find the lowest value F, and put the key and value into the dictionary.
   ```
4. Stop when the goal point is in the explored dictionary.
5. Save the way.

Comment: Should your method `judge()` be returning something other than 0?

Comment: The method judge() is just to complete a dictionary which shows the father-son relationships of each point. It doesnot need to return anything in my plan.

Comment: What is the `shortest_path` function? What do you expect the code here to do that it is not doing?

Comment: Why do you you *expect* this to return? It always returns 0.

Comment: The judge function is a part of the shortest_path function.But I cannot put all the code here cuz I have no right.The judge function here is to judge the actions to the adjacent point of current point.

Comment: @AK47 `dictionary_fs` and `dictionary_ft` are mutable so the changes here will be seen elsewhere.

Comment: @DawnZhang: You're not going to get much help with this because it's not at all clear what your code is supposed to be doing. Since you haven't (and can't) post runable code, we can't try it ourselves and see what's going wrong. I've never heard the name "judge" used in relation to A*, so you need to explain a lot more about what the relationship of the function is to your pseudocode of A* in order to get more help.